# How to authenticate user with SHA1 in Java

Tags: java, linux, authentication, sha1, pureftpd

I used Apache library for hash password for two application in Linux. One of them is Pure-Ftp  and another is my Application. I manually save hashed password in Pure-Ftp passwd file, It works fine and user can use Ftp with given user/password.
In my Application I want to authenticat user, But there is not any checkPassword(clearTextPassword, hashedPassword) function.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Crypt;
...
...
...
String hashedValue = Crypt.crypt(clearTextPassword);
..
```

Comment: Well no, you need to *write* that code. Where are you storing the hashed passwords? It's really unclear what you're asking for here. (It's not clear what relationship there is between your password and FTP...) Also I would personally avoid using SHA-1 as a password hash for any serious work.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: I have thought SHA1 512 is secure, isn't it? I don't want to use bash function. I want to generate a hashed password once in Java, then save it in the database  and Pure-Ftp's passwd file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verifying password, You can hash given simple password with savedHashedPassword as salt:

```
  private static boolean checkPassword(String password, String hashedPassword) {
       String tmpHashedPassword = Crypt.crypt(password, hashedPassword);
       return hashedPassword.equalsIgnoreCase(tmpHashedPassword);
```

}

Crypt.crypt(password) Calculates the digest using the strongest crypt(3) algorithm. A random salt and the default algorithm (currently SHA-512) are used.